# Swagger property required false cause error

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am trying to define an API using Swagger 2.0. In my model I have some object which have optional attributes, so I am trying to insert the Swagger tag "required:false".

When I insert the "required" tag, I am getting an error in the editor and I can't figure why..

My Swagger definition is:

```
definitions:
  Error:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
      message:
        type: string
      fields:
        type: string
```

This is perfectly working. Now I want to specify that the 'message' parameter (for example) is optional. So I try the following:

```
definitions:
  Error:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
      message:
        type: string
        required: false
      fields:
        type: string
```

And now I have an error in the Swagger Editor:

```
 Swagger Error
Expected type array but found type boolean
```

Error details are:

```
Details
Object
code: "INVALID_TYPE"
message: "Expected type array but found type boolean"
path: Array [5]
0: "definitions"
1: "Error"
2: "properties"
3: "message"
4: "required"
level: 900
type: "Swagger Error"
description: "Expected type array but found type boolean"
lineNumber: 41
```

Lines:

```
   [40]   message:
   [41]     type: string
   [42]     required: false
```

Did someone have an idea about what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If only code and fields are mandatory you can do something like:

```
definitions:
  Error:
    type: object
    required: [code, fields]
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
      message:
        type: string
      fields:
        type: string
```